# How do I center photoset posts on my Tumblr theme?

Tags: post, themes, blogs, center, tumblr

I can't seem to find a way to center the photoset posts on my tumblr theme. All the other post types are centered it seems, even the regular photo posts. But for some reason the photoset posts are veering off just a little bit to the right.

Here's the markup of my theme:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>{Title}{block:PostTitle}: {PostTitle}{/block:PostTitle}</title>
    {block:Description}
    <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}">
    {/block:Description}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Tumblr Theme configuration -->
    <meta name="color:Background" content="#FFFFFF"/>
    <meta name="color:Link" content="#0000FF"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#FF0000"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Visited" content="#800080"/>

    <meta name="font:Site Font" content=""/>

    <meta name="text:Footer Text" content=""/>
    <meta name="text:Google Analytics ID" content=""/>

    <meta name="image:Header" content=""/>

    <meta name="if:Show Archive" content="1"/>
    <meta name="if:Show RSS" content="0"/>
    <meta name="if:Show Search" content="0"/>

    <meta name="if:Use Time Ago" content="1"/>
    <meta name="if:Use HighRes Photos" content="1"/>
    <meta name="if:Use Number Pagination" content="1"/>

    <!-- END Tumblr Theme configuration -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{PortraitURL-128}">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/wxrod/Tumblr-HTML5-Blank-Theme/master/css/normalize.min.css">

    <script src="https://raw.github.com/wxrod/Tumblr-HTML5-Blank-Theme/master/js/vendor/modernizr.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

/* THE BASICS */

body {
    background-color: #222;
    background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/ff3ukto/rAYmq57vt/hd_2ac77715bdfbaf4f407dbec9d5d75605.jpg');
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;
}

a { 
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8b1f2e;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

a:hover{ 
    color: #b61a30; 
}

i {
    color: #fff;
}

h1 {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #e0d4a8;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #d7ca98;
    padding-left: 12px;
}


/*POSTS*/

#content {
    color: #c4c4c4;
    background-color: #131313;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 47%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
}

.post {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #212121;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
    width: auto;
}


/*SIDEBAR*/

.sidebar {
    background-color: #ede6cc;
    text-align: justify;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 55%;
    width: 38%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sidebar:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.pagination {
    font-color: #222;
}

/*NAV*/

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 21%;
    width: 89%;
    background-color: #4addae;
    margin-left: 5%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #e8d79a;
    border-bottom: 3px #222 solid;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

/*TAGS*/

ul {
    list-style: lower-roman;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
}

ul li {
    list-style: lower-roman;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
     width: 500px;
}

ul.tags {
    list-style: lower-roman;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

ul.tags li {
display: inline;
list-style: lower-roman;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul.tags li:after {
content: ", ";
color: #aaa;
list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

ul.tags li:last-child:after {
content: "";
list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

img.icon {
    vertical-align:text-top;
    float: right;
    padding: 2px;
}

/*IMAGE SIZE*/

.photoset {
    -webkit-transition: all .40s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .40s linear;
    -o-transition: all .40s linear;
    transition: all .40s linear;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding: none;
}

#content blockquote {
      margin: 0;
      padding: none;
      width: 100%;
}

.photoset:hover {
 -webkit-transition: all .40s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .40s linear;
    -o-transition: all .40s linear;
    transition: all .40s linear;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.photo img {
    border: 7px #272727 solid;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .40s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .40s linear;
    -o-transition: all .40s linear;
    transition: all .40s linear;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.photo img:hover {
   border: 7px #121212 solid;
    -webkit-transition: all .40s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .40s linear;
    -o-transition: all .40s linear;
    transition: all .40s linear;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

/*DATE*/

#date {
    width: inherit;
    padding: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #242424;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #313131;
}

#date a {
    color: #f2e8c4;
}

.jump_page {
padding: 4px 8px;
border: 2px solid #cce45e;
background-color: #ffffff;
color:#585858;
font-family:century gothic;
font-size:11px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.current_page, .jump_page:hover {
padding: 4px 8px;
border: 2px solid #b2c750;
background-color: #cce45e;
color: #ffffff;
font-family:century gothic;
font-size:11px;
text-decoration:none;
}

/* BLOCKQUOTE */

blockquote {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 1px;
    font-style: italic;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    color: #353535;
    border-left: 2px #292929 solid;
    border-right: 2px #292929 solid;
}

footer {
    background-color: #131313;
    padding: 4px;
    border-top: 12px solid #711019;
}
      {CustomCSS}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div id="wrapper">
      <!--PAGE HEADER ******************************************************************* -->
      <header>
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ff3ukto/JKomqv42k/waovntgbanner.jpg" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 5%; top: 0%;">
        {block:IfHeaderImage}
          <div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="{image:Header}"/></a></div>
        {/block:IfHeaderImage}
    <div class="sidebar">
        {block:Description}
          <p id="description">{Description}</p>
        {/block:Description}
        <div class="pagination">
{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}">« </a>{/block:PreviousPage}
{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}"> »</a>{/block:NextPage}
</div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="https://www.etsy.com/shop/weareonly">etsy shop</a>
            <a href="http://weareonly.tictail.com/">tictail shop</a>
            <a href="http://instagram.com/weareonly">instagram</a>
            <a href="http://www.weareonlyvntg.tumblr.com/contact">contact</a>
            <a href="http://www.weareonlyvntg.tumblr.com/tags">tags</a>
        </div>      
      </header>
      <!--PAGE LOOP ******************************************************************* -->
    <center><div id="content">
      <div id="main" role="main">
        {block:Posts}
        <div id="date">
            {block:Date}
                <a href="{Permalink}">{ShortMonth} {DayOfMonthWithZero}, {Year}</a>
            {/block:Date}
            {block:NoteCount}
                - <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount}</a>
            {/block:NoteCount}
        </div>
        <title>{Title} - {block:PostTitle}{PostTitle}{/block:PostTitle}</title>
{block:HasTags}{/block:HasTags}
        {block:Text}
          <article class="post text">
            {block:Title}
            <header>
              <h2 class="entry-title">{Title}</h2>
            </header>
            {/block:Title}
            <p>
              {Body}
            </p>
        {/block:Text}

        {block:Photo}
          <article class="post photo">
            <figure>
                {LinkOpenTag}
                {block:IfUseHighResPhotos}
                  <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
                {/block:IfUseHighResPhotos}
                {block:IfNotUseHighResPhotos}
                  <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
                {/block:IfNotUseHighResPhotos}

              {block:IfNotUseHighResPhotos}
                {block:HighRes}
                <a class="high-res" href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">High-Res</a>
                {/block:HighRes}
              {/block:IfNotUseHighResPhotos}

              {block:Caption}
                <figcaption>
                  <center>{Caption}</center>
                </figcaption>
              {/block:Caption}
              {LinkCloseTag}
            </figure>
        {/block:Photo}

        {block:Photoset}
          <article class="post photoset">
            <figure>
              <center>{Photoset-500}
              {block:Caption}
                <figcaption>
                  {Caption}
                </figcaption>
              {/block:Caption}
            </center></figure>
        {/block:Photoset}

        {block:Quote}
          <article class="post quote">
            <blockquote>{Quote}</blockquote>
            {block:Source}
              <footer>{Source}</footer>
            {/block:Source}
        {/block:Quote}

        {block:Link}
          <article class="post link">
            <header>
              <h2>
                <a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a>
              </h2>
            </header> 
            {block:Description}
            <p> {Description} </p>
            {/block:Description}
        {/block:Link}

        {block:Chat}
          <article class="post chat">
            {block:Title}
            <header>
              <h2>{Title}</h2>
            </header>
            {/block:Title}
            <dialog>
              {block:Lines}
                {block:Label}
                  <dt class="{Alt} {UserNumber}">
                    {Label}
                  </dt>
                {/block:Label}
                <dd> {Line} </dd>
              {/block:Lines}
            </dialog>
        {/block:Chat}

        {block:Audio}
          <article class="post audio">
            <header>
              <h2>
                {block:Artist}
                  {Artist}
                {/block:Artist}

                {block:TrackName}
                  {TrackName}
                {/block:TrackName}
              </h2>
            </header>
            <figure>
              {block:AlbumArt}
                <img src="{AlbumArtURL}"/>
              {/block:AlbumArt}

              {block:AudioPlayer}
                {AudioPlayer}
              {/block:AudioPlayer} 

              {block:Caption}
                <figcaption>
                  {Caption}
                </figcaption>
              {/block:Caption}
            </figure>
        {/block:Audio}

        {block:Video}
          <article class="post video">
            <figure>
              {Video-500}
              {block:Caption}
                <figcaption>
                  {Caption}
                </figcaption>
              {/block:Caption}
            </figure>
        {/block:Video}

        {block:Answer}
          <article class="post answer">
            <dialog>
              <dt><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-16}"> {lang:Asker asked 2}: </dt>
              <dd>{Question}</dd>

              <dd>{Answer}</dd>
            </dialog>
        {/block:Answer}

            <footer>
            {block:RebloggedFrom}
                source / <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootTitle}">{ReblogRootName}</a>
            {/block:RebloggedFrom}

              {block:NoteCount}
                <div class="notes">notes / <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount}</a></div>
              {/block:NoteCount}

              {block:HasTags} 
                <ul>
                  {block:Tags}
                  <li><a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a></li>
                  {/block:Tags}
                </ul>
              {/block:HasTags}

              {block:PermalinkPage}
                {block:PostNotes}<div>{PostNotes-16}</div>{/block:PostNotes}
              {/block:PermalinkPage}   
            </footer>
          </article>
        {/block:Posts}
      </div>
    </div></center>
      <!--PAGE FOOTER ******************************************************************* -->
    </div>
    {block:IfGoogleAnalyticsID}    
    <script>
      var _gaq=[['_setAccount','{text:Google Analytics ID}'],['_trackPageview']];
      (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>
    {/block:IfGoogleAnalyticsID}    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They all appear to be centered already, did you fix this?

Comment: hm... no, I don't believe I fixed it. But I forgot to mention that I'm also using Chrome. What are you using?

Comment: I'm also talking about the actual photosets themselves, the posts that the photosets are in seem to be fine. It's just for some reason the photosets are aligned a little to the right or something. I'm thinking maybe it's just an error I made with the padding property or something.

Comment: In Chrome, you can see that it is perfectly aligned in the middle with equal margins on the left/right: http://cl.ly/image/000P1b1d1m2i

Can you post a specific screenshot of what you're experiencing? I just don't see something that's off-center here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but, for future reference:
If you are wanting to to align a photoset (single post with multiple pictures) post and you are using a custom theme simply:

1. Go into your customize tumblr page
2. Click on 'Edit HTML'
3. Ctrl + F search {block:Photoset}
   the code may look a little like this, it doesn't have to be exact.

```html
{block:Photoset}
<div class="photoset">
    {block:IndexPage}{Photoset-250}{/block:IndexPage}
    {block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-700}{/block:PermalinkPage}
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

4. Now you are going to add  into the code. (without the little star things)

```html
{block:Photoset}
<div class="photoset">
**<div align="center">**
    {block:IndexPage}{Photoset-250}{/block:IndexPage}
    {block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-700}{/block:PermalinkPage}
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    **</div>**
{/block:Photoset}
```

And then update preview and save.